# Chrome not displaying characters despite being installed

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, unicode, chinese

There are quite a few sources online on how to fix Unicode characters not displaying correctly, though most of them just tell you to make sure you have a font installed on your system that contains the Unicode character you want to display.

In my case, the character not displaying correctly (among others) has Unicode code point [U+31D0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/31d0/index.htm) and looks like ㇐, if your browser can correctly display it (it is the 横 (heng2) horizontal stroke in Chinese).

[image]

According to the [list of fonts that support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/31d0/fontsupport.htm)  this code point, [Code2000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/code2000/index.htm) should support this, though after manually searching for this character in Code2000, Code2001, and Code2002, I still could not find it.  I thus installed [BabelStone Han](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/babelstone_han/index.htm), which according to that same list, did support this code point.  Furthermore, this time around, I was able to manually confirm that this font contained code point U+31D0 after installing the font on my system.

Despite, this, however, the character still displays improperly in Chrome.  It does nevertheless display properly in Windows.  For example, see the attached screen-shot (this table is on the [CJKV stroke Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_(CJKV_character)#Use_in_computing)).
[image]

I did find [this supposed fix](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hjI1K8Nb860), but:

1. On the version of Chrome I am using (41.0.2272.76 m (64-bit), which is the current stable release as of this writing) the option "Disable layer squashing" no longer seems to exist.
2. Simply setting "Disable DirectWrite" to "Disable" (which does still exist in this version) does not do the trick.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?